# Change scrollbar color of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have a div with many row (thymeleaf cicle) and so I use a scrollbar to view all elements.
Now i would change the color of this scrollbar but i don't know how. I have read and tried many guides without any result.
This is my scrollbar code in js file:

```
$(window).on("load resize",function() {
    winHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#scrollerCa').css({
        'max-height' : (winHeight)-100 + "px",
        'overflow-y' : "auto",
        'overflow-x' : "hidden",
    });
});
```

Anyone have idea how to change the color? Now is very bad
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use these simple scrollbar CSS attributes:

```
scrollbar-face-color: #000000;  
scrollbar-shadow-color: #2D2C4D;  
scrollbar-highlight-color:#7D7E94;  
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #7D7E94;  
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #2D2C4D;  
scrollbar-track-color: #7D7E94;  
scrollbar-arrow-color: #C1C1D1;
```

Ofcourse you should put this inside `#yourdiv{}` or `.yourdiv{}`

Check [this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/) link.

Comment: can I put this setting in my js?Because i have already use that guide without  result

Comment: Yes just like this:     `$('#scrollerCa').css({
        'max-height' : (winHeight)-100 + "px",
        'overflow-y' : "auto",
        'overflow-x' : "hidden", 'scrollbar-face-color' : '#000000',
    });`

Comment: I have tried this: $('#scrollerCa').css({
   'max-height' : (winHeight)-100 + "px",
   'overflow-y' : "auto",
   'overflow-x' : "hidden",
   'scrollbar-face-color' : '#1922f8',
   'scrollbar-shadow-color': '#1922f8',  
  'scrollbar-highlight-color': '#1922f8',
  'scrollbar-3dlight-color': '#1922f8',  
  'scrollbar-darkshadow-color': '#1922f8',  
  'scrollbar-track-color': '#1922f8',  
  'scrollbar-arrow-color': '#1922f8',  
  });
but the scrollbar is always the same

Answer (score 0):

Use the below jQuery CSS Property,

```
$('#scrollerCa').css({
    'max-height' : (winHeight)-100 + "px",
    'overflow-y' : "auto",
    'overflow-x' : "hidden",
    "background-color": "yellow"
});
```